# Asp.net Email Control

Tags: asp.net, email, gmail

I'm in the beginning stage of building an Asp.net email control. I'm a big fan of asp because a developer can drop a control onto a page and all functionality is bundled into it.
So, my goal is to develop an EmailControl that encapsulates send/recieve into a single server control.

I would appreciate if anyone has some tips or technical references regarding this topic.  For all of you wondering, I AM doing research of my own but some of you may have some additional sites that I could check out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let users send, you just need the basic form elements and the code on the page below to send the mail.

[Sending Email with System.Net.Mail](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx)

.NET doesn't have any native POP3/IMAP support but there are a multitude of libraries available, such as:

[.NET POP3 MIME Client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21377/NET-POP3-MIME-Client)

(This answer assumes by "send/receive" you are referring to implementing a mail client as opposed to a mail server.)

Comment: Yes, it is as a mail client.  Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Beware that Aspnet will be supersede by Aspnet MVC, where these kind of "drag and drop" controls don't exists any more..

Comment: Oh great. I guess I've been out of the technical loop.  I'll check this out.  Thanks